# How to read all @input members in a angular component?

Tags: angular, decorator

I need to read all properties with @Input() decorator in angular component. I tried with reflect and reflect-metadata,but all failed,
how to implement this function?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3#add-the-input-hero-property

Answer (score 5):

```
function getComponentMeta(compType): { inputs, outputs } {
    const props = compType.__prop__metadata__;
    const inputs = [];
    const outputs = [];
    for (const prop in props) {
      const member = props[prop][0];
      if (member.ngMetadataName === 'Input') {
        inputs.push(prop);
      }else if (member.ngMetadataName === 'Output') {
        outputs.push(prop);
      }
    }
    return {
      inputs: inputs.sort(),
      outputs: outputs.sort()
    };
  }
```